# skmaps huge memory leaks by updating SKAnnotation

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, annotations, skmaps

On the map I have placed annotations and I need to hide/show some of them.

I use the same annotations and just call `mapView.updateAnnotation(annotation)` but every call for this function increases memory usage.

Is there another way to achieve hiding/showing Annotation without recreating them and without memory leaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory leak was an issue that we've fixed via this hotfix: http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/7507-Fix-for-quot-iOS-9-2-crashes-quot-the-log-pointing-to-the-GLStateMachine?p=22951#post22951